# Непонятное значение при выводе TimeSpan

Tags: c#, datetime

Мне нужно получить разницу между датой отправки сообщения `timeSended`
и `DateTime.Now`, потаюсь сделать это следующим образом внутри класса `Message`:

```
public class Message : User
    {
        public enum STATUS {SENDED, READED, NOTSENDED}
        public enum SENDED_FROM { CURRENT, ANOTHER}

        public SENDED_FROM sendedFrom { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public DateTime timeSended { get; set; }
        public STATUS status { get; set; }
        public string timeAgo { get; private set; }

        public Message()
        {
            var timeNow = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan ago = timeNow - timeSended;
            if (ago.Days > 30) { timeAgo = $"{(int)(ago.Days/31)} мес."; } //не обращайте внимание на неоднородность, пытался экспериментировать, к сожалению, тщетно
            else if (ago.TotalDays > 7) timeAgo = timeAgo = $"{(int)(timeNow - timeSended).TotalDays / 7} н";
            else if ((timeNow - timeSended).TotalDays > 0) timeAgo = timeAgo = $"{(int)(timeNow - timeSended).TotalDays} д";
            else if ((timeNow - timeSended).TotalHours > 0) timeAgo = timeAgo = $"{(int)(timeNow - timeSended).TotalHours} ч";
            else if ((timeNow - timeSended).TotalMinutes > 0) timeAgo = timeAgo = $"{(int)(timeNow - timeSended).TotalMinutes} мин";
            else timeAgo = "Сейчас";
        }

    }
```

Заполняю объект класса:

```
messages = new List<Models.Message>();
            messages.Add(new Models.Message{

                userId = 1,
                Name = "Lorem Ipsum1",
                ImageResourse = "https://avatarzo.ru/wp-content/uploads/z-za-pobedu.jpg",

                sendedFrom = Models.Message.SENDED_FROM.CURRENT,
                message = "Hi",
                status = Models.Message.STATUS.SENDED,
                timeSended = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3),
            });
```

Проблема в том, что при попытке вывода `timeAgo` выводится: *огромное число* мес.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема? Спасибо)

**UPD:**
Вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш вопрос низкого качества. Ознакомьтесь с информацией из справки [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: зачем весь этот код, если у вас проблема в одной строчке? Выше дал  ссылку на то, как создать минимальный воспросизводимый пример - я уверен на 90%, вы найдете свою проблему, пока будете этот пример нам создавать.

Comment: В данном случае вы могли бы оформить код так, чтобы мы могли запустить его и сразу увидеть проблему. Не страшно если код длинный, главное чтоб его можно было скопировать, запустить, и сразу увидеть проблему

Comment: ну и как бы вы дни за месяцы считаете `$"{(int)(ago.Days)} мес.";`

Comment: `выводится: огромное число мес.` пример вывода?

Comment: @tym32167 добавил скриншот в тему

Comment: @Evk код является часть maui проекта, поэтому думаю, что было бы сложно его просто так запустить

Comment: @tym32167 исправил (скриншот сделан после применения изменений)

Comment: берем 23821, умножаем на 31 и делим на 365, получаем 2023, то есть примерно текущий год. А значит, что ваше timeSended указывает на нулевой год. Замените `timeAgo = $"{(int)(ago.Days/31)} мес.";` на `timeAgo = $"{timeSended} мес.";` и проверьте

Comment: То, что вы делаете, есть в довольно популярной библиотеке [Humanizr](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#humanize-datetime), можете разобрать ее, посмотрев, как там это сделано, ну или взять сразу ее на вооружение. Это так, лишь говорю о том, что уже есть готовые решения.